# PCIe to Thunderbolt on Linux

Tags: linux, pcie, thunderbolt

So I've been Googling forever and can't seem to find any info on this.

I would like to know if there is a PCIe-to-Thunderbolt card that works with Linux (if there are drivers for it).

Has anyone tried installing such a card in a Linux box?

Comment: If anyone could post an answer that works on Windows I'd be grateful.

Comment: @RubyJunk all the cards that i found were for windows. I also learned that the MB needs to have a Thunderbolt header or it wont work.